# Filtering array of objects inside object based on predicate

Tags: c#, linq, filter

Assuming I have an object of some type, containing an array of some other type:

```
public class Mammal
{
    public Leg[] Legs { get; set; }
}

public class Leg
{
    public int Length { get; }
}
```

If I e.g. receive a `Mammal` from some `GetMammals()` call, how would I go about filtering `Legs` in `Mammal` based on a predicate, such as height for example?

```
Mammal.Legs.Where(l => l.Length > 10);
```

Above would return an `IEnumerable<Legs>` which I would then have to find a way to stuff back into `Mammal`, but is there a neat way to perform this action directly on my `Mammal` object, assuming I would have to use this `filteredMammal` object for something else later on?

Comment: LINQ (language integrated *query*) is a query tool, it does not modify. If you want to modify you have to do it yourself.

Comment: As youar array is readonly effectivly you can´t do much. Linq just **returns** collections instead of **modifying** them.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ok then let's assume it's not readonly then.

Comment: You want to modify `Mammal.Legs` property to only have `Leg` objects with `Length > 10` ? If you want to do it in one line, you could write a `Filter` extension method that takes the predicate and also sets the property to the result.

Comment: Eric Lippert on [ForEach](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allready have written the solution yourself. Every linq-method just **returns** a new collection instead of **modifying** the existing one.

In order to do so you´d have to set the returned collection to your mammals property:

```
myMammal.Legs = myMammals.Legs.Where(myPredicate).ToArray();
```

This assumes you can **set** the property.

Another opportunitiy is to write a `Remove`-method:

```
void Remove(Predicate<Leg> predicate)
{
    this.Legs = this.Legs.Where(x => !predicate(x)).ToArray();
}
```

This still requires a `private` setter though.

The best approach is to make `Legs` a `List<Leg>`. Then you can just call [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall):

```
myMammal.Legs.RemoveAll(myPredicate);
```